# saving a photo or file in symfony 1.4 action

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Im having difficulty on saving files or photos in my database.In my action

```
 if($r->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->form->bind($r->getParameter('applicants'), $r->getFiles('applicants'));          
        //$this->form->bind($r->getParameter('applicants'));
        $this->familyForm->bind($r->getParameter('applicant_family_info'));
        if($this->form->isValid() && $this->familyForm->isValid()) {
            $values = $this->form->getValues();
            $familyValues = $this->familyForm->getValues();
            $applicantId = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Applicants')->createOrUpdateObject($values, $familyValues, $this->getUser()->getUsername());
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('good', 'New applicant record created successfully!');
            $this->redirect('loans/new_applicant_loan?applicant_id='.$applicantId);
```

This will save the inputted data minus the photo column..However, if i add $this->form->save(); ,this will save the datas including the photo field,but the photo is duplicate,any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]

with $this->form->save();

[image]

returns null if i remove $this->form->save();By the way, i have two tables for this from,applicants and applicant_family_info

and this ApplicantsTable.class.php

```
public function createOrUpdateObject($values, $infoValues, $currentLoggedInUser, $obj = null) {
    $isUpdate = true;
    if(empty($obj)) {
        $obj = new Applicants();
        $isUpdate = false;
    }

    $db = $this->getConnection();
    $db->beginTransaction();
    foreach($values as $k=>$v) {
        $obj->$k = $v;
    }
    if(!$isUpdate) {
        $obj->created_by = $currentLoggedInUser;
        $obj->date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
        $obj->updated_by = $currentLoggedInUser;
        $obj->date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    $obj->save();
    if(!$isUpdate) {
        $applicantId = $db->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        $applicantId = $obj->id;
    }

    if(!$isUpdate) {
        $info = new ApplicantFamilyInfo();
    } else {
        $info = $obj->ApplicantFamilyInfo;
    }
    foreach($infoValues as $k=>$v) {
        $info->$k = $v;
    }

    $info->applicant_id = $applicantId;
    $info->save();

    $db->commit();

    return $applicantId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `form->save()` and then call `createOrUpdateObject()` you are saving your object to the database twice, that's why you have the duplicate entry in your applicants table.

The 'magic' why in the first case you get the filename and in the second not lies in the way how Symfony handles the uploaded files. In the second case you read the values from the form, including the `photo` field, but this field in fact does not have a value set (there is a file associated to that field, but it's not its' "value"). When you first execute the form's `save` method Symfony handles the file upload (moves the file from temp location to the uploaded files, changes names, etc.) and in return sets the value of your `photo` field giving you the full physical path to the file.

Do you really need the `createOrUpdateObject` function? Does do it anything else than just saving the forms? If you need to modify any additional values you can always use Doctrine's lifecycle functions: `preSave`, `preInsert`, `postDelete`, etc.

Comment: Yes i need the createOrUpdateObject function.I would like to populate created_by,and updated_by columns automatically.

Comment: You can add the `Timestampable` behaviour to your table and Doctrine will populate them for you.

Comment: Thank you Michal Trojanowski.I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling,and trying, I finally found  a solution for my problem.The file path successfully saved in mysql and no duplication this time.Here is my edited code in action:

```
if($r->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->form->bind($r->getParameter('applicants'), $r->getFiles('applicants'));  
        $photo = $this->form->getValue('photo');
        $photo->save();     
        $this->familyForm->bind($r->getParameter('applicant_family_info'));
        if($this->form->isValid() && $this->familyForm->isValid()) {
            $values = $this->form->getValues();
            //$this->form->save();
            //$values = $this->form->getValues('photo');
            //$photo->save();
            //$filename = 'photo'.sha1($photo->getOriginalName());
           //$extension = $photo->getExtension($photo->getOriginalExtension());
           //$photo->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'));// . $filename . $extension);
            //$photo->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/'.$photo . date('Ym'));// . '/' . $filename . $extension);

            //$photo->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/photos/'.$photo);
            $familyValues = $this->familyForm->getValues();
            $applicantId = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Applicants')->createOrUpdateObject($values, $familyValues, $this->getUser()->getUsername());
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('good', 'New applicant record created successfully!');
            $this->redirect('loans/new_applicant_loan?applicant_id='.$applicantId);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is mysql
[image]

and here,in my templates comes my new problem..

```
<?php echo $applicant->photo ?>
```

Will render filename instead the image(C:\wamp\www\ian_loans\web\uploads/photos\85c4153ed074657c58db526e5f8349183cb08469.jpg)
and i tried

```
<td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="/uploads/photos/<?php echo($applicant->photo)?>" width="129" height="129" /></td>
```

and the photo never show up...What I am missing here?

Comment: First it's not a good idea to save the photo before you validate the form. If the form is invalid you will end up with the file saved on your server. It's also a security issue as you let people upload any kind of file to your server. Other problem is that you save the physical path to the file and you should save only the filename (or URL) as this is what you need when displaying the image. You should change this value in the `createOrUpdate` funciton.